# USB 2.0 port does not work, USB 3.0 ports do work, running Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: usb

I have 3 USB3.0 ports and 1 USB2.0 port on my Laptop (w230st clevo). Unfortunately,the USB2.0 port does not work, despite being shown on lookup with `lsusb`, output shown below.
Strange is, that `lsusb` shows 3 USB2.0 ports and one USB3.0 ports - so it could be that Ubuntu misinterprets the hardware. 
Another piece of information that I can provide is that bootable USB-sticks also only work with the USB3.0 ports, and if the bootable USB-stick is plugged to the USB2.0 port it isn't even shown in the bios bootdevice menu.

Here the output of `lsusb`:

```
user@w230st:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 041e:3042 Creative Technology, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

and the output of `lspci`:

```
user@w230st:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 12)
```

and the output of `dmesg | grep USB`

```
user@w230st:~$ dmesg | grep USB
[    0.669303] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.669440] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.683055] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    0.683107] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.683148] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.683398] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.683609] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.699040] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    0.699089] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.699130] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.699366] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.699558] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.699607] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.699723] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    0.699961] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.700002] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.700239] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.704226] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    0.704293] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    0.704331] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.706093] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.994752] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.127059] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8008
[    1.127104] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.127395] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.238476] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.370775] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    1.370777] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.370999] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.538132] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.556454] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=041e, idProduct=3042
[    1.556456] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.721920] usb 3-7: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.742075] usb 3-7: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07da
[    1.742077] usb 3-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.909718] usb 3-8: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    1.985912] usb 3-8: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=0400
[    1.985914] usb 3-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   12.050722] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[ 1202.564626] usb 3-8: USB disconnect, device number 4
```

At the moment I am kind of lost of how to best analyse the problem. I would like to know whether this is a hardware problem or one of Ubuntu.

Here the output of `dmesg | tail` right after plugging an usb-stick to the 2.0 port:

```
user@w230st:~$ dmesg | tail
[  266.418505] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  266.501513] pci 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D3cold
[  266.505492] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Event TRB for slot 2 ep 2 with no TDs queued?
[  266.505498] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Event TRB for slot 2 ep 0 with no TDs queued?
[  269.579117] net_ratelimit: 135 callbacks suppressed
[  269.579133] r8169 0000:04:00.1 eth0: link up
[  269.579148] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  278.254899] hid-generic 0005:045E:0700.0002: unknown main item tag 0x0
[  278.254953] input: Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:34/input15
[  278.255105] hid-generic 0005:045E:0700.0002: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.00 Mouse [Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000] on b4:b6:76:94:7c:bb
```

Note, I did not plug a bluetooth usb-stick related to the mouse, which connect directly to the laptops bluetooth.

All **id: usb** devices found by `sudo lshw`:

```
*-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: Lynx Point USB xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:41 memory:f7a00000-f7a0ffff
*-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: Lynx Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7a1c000-f7a1c3ff
*-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: Lynx Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7a1b000-f7a1b3ff
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `dmesg | tail` when you connect any device to the port?

Comment: I updated my post with the info you requested. Thank you for having a look into the issue. I must admit, I fear the port is dead, because even with a bootable usb-device plugged, that is not shown in the bios, whereas bootable devices are shown, when plugged to other usb-ports on the same notebook.

Comment: If you bootable media doesn't detect in `Bios Boot Menu` then how can you say that it is Ubuntu error! You should contact to your device manufacturer. Anyway I also want you to confirm. Run this command in terminal : `sudo lshw -html > myhardware.html` and then open it with any browser: `firefox myhardware.html`. Finally check the **Version** of all **id: usb**. Reply what you get. You can also post the output of this command: `sudo lshw` here.

Comment: @Kumar - exactly, that is my fear! However, my lsusb output suggests (if my interpretation is valid) that there are 4 usb ports. However, they seem to be identified incorrectly in terms of their version. I will post what you asked for in the main thread.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem here. Any progress?  
Can't boot in the bios on the USB 2 but they show in the lsusb

Comment: I really cannot explain why but my problem is fixed. I booted on a lubunut live usb and it worked, rebooted into my normal ubuntu to let you know and now it works there too. I hope it's not just random and a sign of my usb ports will soon die.

Comment: @Victor - what is the model of your pc? I think for me the problem is hardware-side. However, I will try to boot using the lubuntu live usb option. Did that with Ku- and Xubuntu, which did not work however.

Comment: @cuichi  ASUS U36SD. But it stopped working again and the lubuntu boot stunt didn't change anything this time so it's clearly hardware, which s***s but at least I can understand it because the previous solution really didn't make any any sense at all.  Good luck to you.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: To be honest, I did not find a solution. It look like that the power supply cables for those ports weren't connected upon assembly. Should I delete or close this question?